# How to use multiple results from one query as input for a second query to generate report

Tags: mysql

So i have this script im using to find a list of Codes and associated Group names for those codes that meet the criteria in the where clause

```
SELECT
  cc.code AS `cc Code`,
  ii.ii_groupname AS `II Group Name`
FROM ds
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dd
    ON ds.dd_id = dd.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ii
    ON ds.ii_id = ii.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dcc
    ON ds.id = dcc.dos_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cc
    ON dcc.cpt_id = cc.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN bil
    ON ds.bil_id = bil.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cs
    ON bil.claim_status = cs.id
WHERE cs.status = 'Pending'
AND dd.date_of_service BETWEEN '2017/01/01' AND '2018/08/31'
AND (dcc.r_code = '42'
OR dcc.r_code = '36')
GROUP BY cc.code,
         ii.ii_groupname
```

this will return a list of codes and associated group names this is short snip

```
cc code II Group Name
111     Team 1
2241    TWR
2241    TMA
2777    AHI
2777    AST
2777    BAC
2777    BH
2777    CEI
2777    DMS
2777    FPC
2777    FFN
2777    FFN 2
2777    IS
5664    AE
5664    CEI
5664    DMS
5664    UA
23456   AE
23456   CEI
23456   Team Alpha
23456   MB
23456   PI
23456   PTC
23456   SGC
23456   TWR
23456   USAA
```

a given code can be used by multiple group names.

i then need to take the results of this list of codes and group names and then get the avg amount for a few fields for each given code and associated group name, if it was done manually script is like this

```
    SELECT
     cc.code AS `cc Code`,
  ii.ii_groupname AS `II Group Name`
  CAST(AVG(dcc.amount_allowed) AS decimal(10, 2)) `AVG Allowed`,
  CAST(AVG(dcc.paid_amount) AS decimal(10, 2)) `Paid Avg`
  FROM ds
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dd
    ON ds.dd_id = dd.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ii
    ON ds.ii_id = ii.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dcc
    ON ds.id = dcc.dos_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cc
    ON dcc.cpt_id = cc.id
 WHERE date_of_service BETWEEN '2017/01/01' AND '2019/08/31'
 AND (dcc.r_code = '42' OR dcc.r_code = '36')
 and cc.code = '23456'
 and ii.ii_groupname = "Team Alpha"
 dcc.amount_allowed > 0
```

So what i want to do is take that list of codes and group names from the first query and use it for the 2nd one replacing the code and group name automatically and giving me output for all the cc.code and group names showing those avg. if it was just one value i needed i could use Include subquery but since i need both the code and groupname from it im not sure best way to do this.  Thanks for any help

Comment: ok im not seeing how that helps me ? ive tried to present the queries im using to get the list of codes and groups  and then i need to figure out how to have second script take that output and give me avgs for all of those codes/groups. sorry if im missing something

Comment: ok so do you have something that can help ? im searching the site/the internet/etc looking for possible solutions (for several hours at this point) if you can point me to something that would help that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have everything I got.

Comment: ok im confused, maybe i missed it, i didnt see anything in your link related to my issue.  hopefully someone else can help me.  Thanks anyway

Comment: i dont see how i could create a sample db using my tables etc as each of the tables used in the queries above have dozens of columns in them, so entering all that into some temp tool would take to much time etc, if that is what was being asked i thought i included the details of my scripts clearly and output im trying to get. doesnt seem helpful for the "expert" people to downvote me because of this. just trying to get some help.

Comment: And note that in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate. Conversely, where aggregate functions are used in conjunction with non-aggregated columns, a GROUP BY clause is useful.

Comment: sorry i dont know how i could pare down all those tables and still have them function as my db does without taking days, i just dont have that expertise to do faster i guess and i have a deadline of tomorrow evening.  i have tried removing the group by you mentioned from the 1st query that gets the list of codes and associated groups, doing this 3x the rows returned as each entry for group that used code is listed more times with same group name. im currently looking at trying to use multiple column include in the where clause to see if that will work

Comment: I'd like to help, and perhaps I speak do others too; who knows? But I can't unless you can simplify the problem to its essence.

Comment: Also, just another observation: dcc, cc,  ii, dd, and cs are all inner joins

Comment: as simple as i can make it i guess is i need to extract for all dd.id , the code# and associate groups where their status is pending, their date of service is between the dates, and their r_code is one of the 2 listed. when i run that it returns around 3600 rows., i need to take that list of codes and associated groups and then for each group and code find the avg amount_allowed and paid amount for the associated code and group for all dd.id no matter their status where the amount_allowed was >0

Comment: That sounds like a more manageable problem. I suspect if that was your question, and it was accompanied by a sample data set and desired result, an answer would be forthcoming.  3600 results is probably overkill. 12 is usually more than enough to illustrate the problem and its edge cases, but then you know that already.

Comment: ive been working on it for about 6 hours now, think i might be getting somewhere, if not i will try and go to one of those sites and setup test env for it in the morning,

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working via adding a subquery in the where clause utilizing IN
like

```
where (cc.code,ii.ii_group_name) IN (select cc.code, ii.ii_group_name from ...)
```

this would then return those 2 fields to the main query to run.